# How can I debug vue cli plugins with vscode?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, vue-cli, vscode-debugger

I am developing some vue cli plugins like [vuetify's](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify) to create a boilerplate to other developers, but sometimes I need to debug it. I am really tired of using console.log. How can I debug this kind of plugins especially with vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's done.

I just added to main project's package.json > scripts object these lines (not the cli plugin's itself package.json)

```
 "debug:cli": "node --inspect-brk --preserve-symlinks ./node_modules/.bin/vue invoke vue-cli-plugin-hello-world",
 "debug:vueui": "node --inspect --preserve-symlinks ./node_modules/.bin/vue ui"
```

(Also you can use **local vue cli** service with ./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service path. **Global vue cli** service is different.)

When I trigger it via yarn run debug:cli or debug:vueui, I can debug them with chrome://inspect or vscode (cmd shift p > attach node process)

Also if you want to debug it with vscode directly, here is my vscode launch.json file.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug my vue cli plugin",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "debug:cli"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "port": 9229
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Vue UI",
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "debug:vueui"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```